# CSS how to make the background to have size of content

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image]

I attached an image with a text, I want the element background to have the same size as the text, which would be the same size as the highest letter. I cannot find a css property to do it.

This is my expected result:
[image]

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: Are you looking for `line-height: 1`?

Comment: Just use a `span` with no `padding` properties ..  `<span style="background-color:#0000FF; color:#FFF; font-size:26px;">Our Offer</span>`

Comment: If your line-height is already at 1 and you get this, it is because of the font you are using. Most fonts will have a little bit of space around the actual letters so using background colour, you will not be able to do what you desire. If this only needs to apply for short words then you can fake the background with another element with a fixed height having the blue background colour and give your text postition so it will be above the bg element

Answer (score 2):

Just use a span with no padding properties ..

```html
<span style="background-color:#0000FF; color:#FFF; font-size:26px; padding: 0;">
    <a href="" style="color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;">
        Our Offer
    </a>
</span>
```

**UPDATE**

As @Huangism mentioned, fonts all have their own spacing above and below making room for the swing on a g or j for instance.

I defined the font in this example, because the CSS in your document might not match the font, and have different spacing above and below.  You can then manipulate height and line-height to compensate, and reach the desired output.  Note that I set the span to `inline-block` otherwise the height property is ignored:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <a href="" style="color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;">Our Offer</a>
</span>
```

Comment: this text is a link (anchor tag), it doesn't work

Comment: Sure it does .. See updated answer.

Comment: nope, still the same

Comment: You can see that my snip works "stand alone" ..  You obviously have competing CSS.  Use your developers console and tweak the values until you find the competing code.

Comment: It doesn't work because the blue bg is not close to the edges of the letter. This is dependent on the font, most fonts always have space around the letters

Comment: @Huangism yes very true .. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities that occur to me. One is the cleaner one but it still has a slight gap at the top and bottom. The other really has no spacing but is very unflexible.

**1 Variant**

```css
.c {
  display: inline;
  background-color:blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 34px;  
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <p class="c">Our Offer</p>
</div>
```

**2 Variant**

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 165px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background-color: blue;
} 

div.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -2px;    
  font-size:34px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">Our Offer</div>
</div>
```